# Why does Google Apps Script return a URL rather than a PDF file when I try to create PDF from a Spreadsheet?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

Unlike this recent issue [[Not allow to access from one to other Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382538/not-allow-to-access-from-one-to-other-google-spreadsheet/19383525#19383525) ] (Q4-2014), I want to use **UrlFetchApp.fetch()** rather than **[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]** to convert a single sheet from Google Spreadsheet into a PDF in my Google Drive. UrlFetchApp.fetch() will allow me to choose landscape vs. portrait and several other output control parameters. **file.getAs()** lacks such formatting options.

My problem is that, using UrlFetchApp.fetch(), I get back a text file containing a URL for the PDF, rather than the PDF itself.

```
Example of the resulting file:
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>">"The document has moved
<A "HREF="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QTXXHEsOd9pZTfXxxxxxxxxxxphO4gn/export?"">"exportFormat=pdf&amp;gid=1&amp;gridlines=false&amp;printtitle=false&amp;size=A4&amp;sheetnames=false&amp;fzr=true&amp;portrait=true&amp;fitw=true">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Here is my code (almost entirely borrowed from Ben Oliver at https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benoliver999/9000157/raw/pdfmachine

```
function POtoDrive(){
var key = "1QTLGHEsOd9pZTfXM1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxO4gntxPFTutYKQvE"; // Spreadsheet ID to create PDF from.
var pdf = spreadsheetToPDF(key);                          // Runs function below
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('newPdfs');        // A file does indeed get created in that folder 
folder = folder.next();
folder.createFile(pdf);                                   // Creates the PDF based on var below.
}

function spreadsheetToPDF(key) {   
var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds";
oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  

var requestData = {
"method": "GET",
"oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
"oAuthUseToken": "always",
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
};

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var key = doc.getId();
var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
var name = "simplename.pdf";
// Makes PDF 
var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+key+"&exportFormat=pdf&gid=1&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&size=A4&sheetnames=false&fzr=true&portrait=true&fitw=true", requestData).getBlob().setName(name); 
return pdf;
}
```

If I put that URL into my browser, I can download a PDF at that looks good. But, I want the script to actually drop a PDF file into my Google Drive. It's as though I'm getting back a pointer, or getting back a PDF-generating URL, rather than the PDF file itself. How do I get the actual PDF file to be created in my Google Drive?

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so please be kind about any breaches of etiquette. Thanks. :)

Comment: Have a look at  this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-ptrint-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pd

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not use the right url for new spreadsheets, below is a working version :

(borrowed [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-ptrint-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pd))

```
function test(){
  var id = '16vApdixgE6_________96QXEi1qvD58CSFJw';
  var index = 0;
  var name = 'test.pdf';
  DriveApp.createFile(spreadsheetToPDF(id,index,name))
}


// Convert spreadsheet to PDF file.
function spreadsheetToPDF(id,index,name)
{
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //define usefull vars
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  var scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";

  //make OAuth connection
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

  //get request
  var request = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "google",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  //define the params URL to fetch
  var params = '?gid='+index+'&fitw=true&exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&gridlines=false';

  //fetching file url
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/export"+params, request);
  blob = blob.getBlob().setName(name);

  //return file
  return blob;
}
```

Comment: Please note that OAuthConfig is no longer supported! https://cloud.google.com/blog/changes-oauth-apps-script

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58728448/1251007 for a working version ...